# jQuery doesn't work except when I copy and paste into google chrome console, it work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<textarea cols="5" disabled id="textareRSAKeypair">
  @Model["keypair"]
</textarea>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="downloadKeypair">DownLoad Key</a>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("a#downloadKeypair").click(function () {
    var now = new Date().toString();
    var filename = 'RSAKeyPair_' + now + ".txt";
    $("a#downloadKeypair").attr('Download', filename);

    this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent($('#textareRSAKeypair').text());
  });
</script>
```

My jQuery code doesn't work on the page, but when I copy and paste it into the console (google chrome), it works well. I don't know why. I tried adding the `document.load` method, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is `a#downloadKeypair` being dynamically loaded into the DOM?

Comment: do you see any errors in the console (normally ctrl shift i)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I have a view contain textaera + jquery. I tried add all jquery into $(document).ready(function(){. myjquerycode.}); but it not work. How can i do now.

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. only this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the ready event :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a#downloadKeypair").click(function () {
        var now = new Date().toString();
        var filename = 'RSAKeyPair_' + now + ".txt";
        $("a#downloadKeypair").attr('Download', filename);
        this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent($('#textareRSAKeypair').text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your code inside $(document).ready function.
It may be your problem.